# How to sum each row and replace each value in row with sum?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

If I have a data frame like this:

```
   1  2  3  4  5
 1 2  4  5 NaN 3
 2 3  5  6  1  2
 3 3  1  1  1  1
```

How do I sum each row and replace the values in that row with the sum so I get something like this:

```
   1   2  3  4  5
 1 14 14 14 NaN 14
 2 17 17 17 17  17
 3 7  7  7  7   7
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) for replace all non missing values by `sum`:

```
df = df.mask(df.notnull(), df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
    1   2   3     4   5
1  14  14  14   NaN  14
2  17  17  17  17.0  17
3   7   7   7   7.0   7
```

Or use [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
arr = df.values
a = np.broadcast_to(np.nansum(arr, axis=1)[:, None], df.shape)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.where(np.isnan(arr), np.nan, a),
                  index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

#alternative
df[:] = np.where(np.isnan(arr), np.nan, a)
print (df)
      1     2     3     4     5
1  14.0  14.0  14.0   NaN  14.0
2  17.0  17.0  17.0  17.0  17.0
3   7.0   7.0   7.0   7.0   7.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `mul`

```
df.notnull().replace(False,np.nan).mul(df.sum(1),axis=0).astype(float)
      1     2     3     4     5
1  14.0  14.0  14.0   NaN  14.0
2  17.0  17.0  17.0  17.0  17.0
3   7.0   7.0   7.0   7.0   7.0
```